# Mutable with logic inside or immutable with logic outside?

Tags: object-oriented, class-design, immutability, side-effect

I know immutable objects are preferred to mutable objects for reasoning and maintenance. But in occasions making a class immutable have some costs, let me explain it with a simple example:

```
class Mutable  
{
    private int i;
    public Mutable(int _i) { i = _i}
    public void Print() // impure function
    {
         print(i);
         i++;   // logic inside
    }
}

... caller

Immutable m = new Mutable(1);
while (true)
{        
    m.Print();
}
```

I call it mutable because its internal state changes and `Print` varies on each call.

Versus.

```
class Immutable  
{
    private int i;
    public Mutable(int _i) { i = _i}
    public int Print() // pure function
    {
         print(i);
         return i;  // returns its state  
    }
}

... caller
int i =1;
while (true)
{
    Immutable im = new Immutable(i);
    i = im.Print(); // get the previous obeject's state
    i++; // logic outside
}
```

Preferring immutable solution make me to do a lot of work outside of an object which was supposed to encapsulate that logic.

---

My actual problem (**you may skip the example below**)

I have a class which draws a text in a box:

```
class TextDrawer
{
   private string text;
   private Rectangle box;
   public TextDrawer(_text, _box) {...}
   public void DrawTextInBox()
   {
   }
}
```

It is probable that the `Text` overflows from the box and part of it wasn't written. I should know the remaining unwritten part to draw it in a new box.(in fact I take an snapshot of the old box as a video frame and need to make a new frame for the remaining text to make a video of the text)

Now I have two options:

1- Make the `TextDrawer` mutable (its internal state is mutable) and `DrawTextInBox` a non-pure function and on each call it draws the remaining part of text in the box.

```
class TextDrawer
{

   private string text;
   private Rectangle box;
   private string remaining;   

   public TextDrawer(_text, _box)
   {
      remaining = text = _text;
      box = _box;
   }    
   public void DrawTextInBox()
   {
      draw as you can from remaining
      update remaining part;
   }
}
```

2- Keep the `TextDrawer` immutable and `DrawTextInBox` a pure function which returns the remaining part, then the caller should keep track of the remaining and pass it again to the `TextDrawer` or instantiate a new `TextDrawer` by the remaining text until there is nothing to write.

```
class TextDrawer
{
   private string text;
   private Rectangle box;
   public TextDrawer(_text, _box) { ... }
   public string DrawTextInBox()
   {
       draw as you can from text;
       return remaining part;
   }
}
```

The second approach is immutable but actually shifts the responsibility of tracking the remaining part outside of the class. The first approach is mutable, but it encapsulates the logic and just need a call to `DrawTextInBox` to draw the remaining part.

---

**Question**: The logic of the above examples was simple but this logic could be more complex, then I don't know whether to extract this logic from a class in order to make it immutable or let it be mutable and have the logic inside?

Comment: In both cases, `TextDrawer` has settable properties, so in neither case is `TextDrawer` immutable.  Also, even if `TextDrawer` had no settable properties, still, `RECT` is mutable, therefore any class containing a `RECT` is also mutable.  Perhaps you are missing something with respect to what `immutable` means?

Comment: @MikeNakis We should assume `RECT` is immutable for the sake of argument.  However, you're right about being able to assign these properties causing `TextDrawer` to not be immutable.

Comment: @MikeNakis  I made both properties private, they just can be passed to the constructor, but the point still remains.

Comment: `The second approach is immutable but actually shifts the responsibility of updating the remaining part outside of the class.` I don't get this statement. With both options you have to make a second call to `DrawTextInBox` to draw the remaining part. The only difference is whether the remaining part is kept internally or returned explicitly.

Comment: @Doval, maybe my understanding of immutability is incorrect, I think in the second approach the internal state of the object changes, so the `DrawTextInBox` is not pure and calling it each time makes a different result.(Am I correct?) anyway it is something I don't like about an object, what is called?

Comment: You are correct in that it's not pure, but I don't see how the immutable solution "shifts the responsibility of updating the remaining part outside of the box" when *both* solutions require a second call to `DrawTextInBox`.

Comment: @Doval in my view, the second approach doesn't need to make a second call on the same object, it gets the remaining, make a new object of `TextDrawer` with this part and calls its `DrawTextInBox`

Comment: @Ahmad That's still two method calls, even if they're being done to different objects. It's the same amount of work. You could return a new `TextDrawer` instead of a string in solution 2 and both examples would look practically the same: `drawer.DrawTextInBox(); drawer.DrawTextInBox();` vs `drawer.DrawTextInBox().DrawTextInBox()`.

Comment: @Doval Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/22838/discussion-between-ahmad-and-doval).

Comment: @Doval I tried to make a new simple example to convey my meaning, please consider it, hope that be illustrating

Comment: @Doval yes, right, sorry! now I got your statement, "`It shifts the responsibility of tracking (not updating) of the remaining text`". However you answered the question in your answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your example:

```
int i =1;
while (true)
{
    Immutable im = new Immutable(i);
    i = im.Print(); // get the previous obeject's state
    i++; // logic outside
}
```

`Immutable` should return *the new state* that the mutable solution would've stored, i.e. `i + 1`. *You already have the old state*. Returning the old state and forcing the caller to update the state himself is pointless. You did this correctly in your real problem, where you return the remaining part of the string instead of the original string.

You should prefer an immutable solution unless you have good reasons otherwise. A good reason may be that the immutable solution is too slow, but first you have to clearly define what's "fast enough" and profile the application to show that the bottleneck is your immutable class and that the mutable alternative will solve the problem.

Comment: You are right my example differs with the actual problem. if we call `i` state,  `Immutable` should return `i+1` and the difference is performance; But if I call it **logic**, it is something that `Mutable` does it internally but `Immutable` doesn't care. Preferring immutable solution make me to do a lot of work outside of an object which was supposed to encapsulate that logic. You can regard the `Mutable` a counter or a timer, they are good objects, not?! (Just I doubt!)

Comment: Or maybe you mean that the right way is instead of updating the state inside the object, I should always update the state and return it in an Immutable solution. That makes sense!!

Comment: `You should prefer an immutable solution` -- As part of a UI?  UI's are naturally mutable... Is it your position that a textbox object be replaced with a new textbox object every time some property on the textbox changes?

Comment: @RobertHarvey He asked a broad question, I gave him a broad answer.  You can always compute the new state that the UI will present in a purely functional way (not necessarily as efficiently, and your language of choice may make this awkward.) For the particular problem Ahmad gave I don't see any difficulty. He's just sequentially transforming and presenting some state. Returning the new state makes the transformation more obvious, and has less chance of causing trouble if two references to the same `TextDrawer` ever exist. Anyways, I used "prefer" precisely because there are exceptions.

Comment: @RobertHarvey I think the immutable philosophy doesn't care what is your object, mutable or immutable solution should be regardless of the object (in theory).

Comment: @RobertHarvey I also don't get why some are concerned about changing a property which doesn't affect the behavior of an object. in my view the textbox should be immutable in its behavior but it's not important to change its back color or text color... they are somethings occurs on UI and therefore are not a concern. Am I right?! is it important?

Comment: @Ahmad: In a desktop application a GUI normally holds the current state to be displayed and therefore it is mutable. In a web application you can render the whole page at each request so, unless you use JavaScript to modify the current page, a web application can be seen as an immutable GUI: immutable snapshots are produced on the server and sent to the client.

Comment: The goal of functional programming isn't to disallow mutability, it is to make mutability explicit (paraphrased quote). Likewise, functional program doesn't try to hide the steps involved in rendering a textbox - it tries to expose the steps so that the caller can have very fine grained control. In this question, the steps involve first computing the word bounding boxes from the string, checking that against the boundary, then compute the wrapping. A functional programming approach will expose those steps to the caller. Now you can see places where immutability can / cannot apply.

Comment: @rwong: Good points. In a GUI the mutable parts can be confined to a small portion of the code.